# How to search between two numbers that have a prefix?

Tags: mysql, between

I am trying to search between two numbers in my database. The problem is the numbers have a prefix in front of them i.e LH123

I know searching for numbers I can just use:

```
and JobNo >=  38308 and JobNo <= 38337
```

But not sure how to search when the number has a prefix in front of it. I tried using BETWEEN but this isn't just returning the numbers I searched. This should return 10, but the query doesn't stop when it reaches LH7010 and keeps going until it reaches LH700999.

```
and JobNo BETWEEN 'LH7000' and 'LH7010'
```

Is there a way to use BETWEEN to only search for those exact numbers or is there another way to search?

Comment: try MySQL CAST https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp .E.G: "and CAST(JobNo AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 7000 and 7010"

Comment: @PrasadWargad this didn't work. It is still returning numbers outside of the range

Comment: try this one, I forgot to replace the prefix in earlier comment, need to replace prefix because we are converting field in INTEGER and then finding number within a given range. "and CAST(REPLACE(JobNo, "LH", "") AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 7000 and 7010"

Comment: @PrasadWargad But the job number is saved as LH7000 in the database. If I am removing the prefix characters and just searching for 7000 it will not find this number because it doesn't exist

Comment: Correct job number is saved as LH7000 and when we use REPLACE for a field in query the value for that field becomes 7000 and that's the value we are comparing. So it should work, I guess.

Comment: @PrasadWargad Ok I understand. Thank you this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the prefix is always 2 chars long then extract the integer part and compare integers like this:

```
and substr(jobno, 3) + 0 between substr('LH7000', 3) + 0 and substr('LH7010', 3) + 0
```

MySql does implicit conversion of the string to integer with `... + 0`

Comment: Does the " + 0" cause the value to be re-cast as an int?  If so, then this works, but it would make a better answer if you explain that.  (I was going to suggest doing an explicit CAST() after extracting the substring.)

Comment: @JDM I did add a simple explanation.

Comment: But the job number is saved as LH7000 in the database. If I am removing the prefix characters and just searching for 7000 it will not find this number

Comment: You remove the prefix of all the operands and the result is a condition like: `<jobno without the prefix> between 7000 and 7010`